# Swift 4 conversion error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSAttributedStringKey'

Tags: swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

When I converted from Swift 3 to Swift 4 I got some error on the "NSAttributedStringKey".

Here's My Code:

```
func height(_ width: CGFloat, font: UIFont, lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode?) -> CGFloat {
    var attrib: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: font]
    if lineBreakMode != nil {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode!
        attrib.updateValue(paragraphStyle, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue)
    }
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(DBL_MAX))
    return ceil((self as NSString).boundingRect(with: size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:attrib, context: nil).height)
}
```

Here's My Error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSAttributedStringKey'

Any suggestion? I'm new in iOS so please be more precise.

Comment: What is the `rawValue` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the use of `.rawValue` for the `.paragraphStyle` key.

Also note that for Swift 4.2 (or later) you need to replace any use of `NSAttributedStringKey` with `NSAttributedString.Key`.

`DBL_MAX` is deprecated. Use `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` instead of `CGFloat(DBL_MAX)`.

Force-unwrapping the optional `lineBreakMode` parameter is going to cause your app to crash if `nil` is passed in.